# Check if multiple fields exists, if not return all items in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, query-string

I'm sorry I couldn't formulate the title well. But my problem is that using query string parameters, I want to return accordingly registered documents from my Mongo collection. Let's say I have this url entered:

```
myurl.com/getbooks?lang=en&cat=fiction&x=y
```

Then I'm passing all query params from client to server within an `options` object like this:

```
options = {lang: 'en', cat: 'fiction', x: 'y'}
```

So when I receive the `options` object in the server, I will use its fields to run the code to find the match for retrieving the relevant books:

```
var lang = options.lang;
var cat = options.cat;
var x = options.x;

Books.find({book_language: lang, book_category: fiction, x: x })
```

This works great, except a very obvious case, which is that **if no query parameters are entered for either or all of the fields; Mongo returns no document, whereas it should return all. Because the field is undefined.** Of course I can exhaustively write a long `if else` function that goes through all possibilities, but I have 4 different params which in total makes 12 different scenarios. So it is not an elegant solution (yet I have a couple more conditions in the server to add).

Therefore I need a solution that modularly checks if the query is not entered for any field, then consequentially returns all, which is the default.

Comment: FYI: When your object gets serialized all of the undefined values will be removed, leaving you with fewer properties.

Comment: What do you mean serialised? This seems like an ideal way, but then it amounts to the same thing just on the client instead...

Comment: Consider `var obj = {a: undefined, b:1}; JSON.stringify(obj) === '{"b":1}'`

Answer (score 1):

This is not that elegant, and not fast, but imo it nicer than writing 12 if statements:

```
var obj = {a: void 0, b: 1, c: 2};
var filled = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) { 
  return obj[key] !== void 0;  
}); 
console.log(filled); // ["b", "c"]
if (filled.length === 3) { 
  Book.find(obj); 
}
```

Comment: Actually I found the best way I think, inspired from yours. Why don't we just delete the properties if the value is undefined, before sending to server? Well, actually yours do more or less that no...? We can just send the array at the end.

Comment: You have an object*, and the values will be deleted before they are send to the server if you are using `JSON.stringify` - I assume you are - to make a stringed representation of your data that can be send to the server.

Comment: That's right, now I see. Will try this tomorrow. Now falling asleep :) Thanks!

Comment: @Emo No problem at all, we are here to inspire each other :-)